# DOM Collections: How to browse contents, and unknown items in links collection

Tags: html, dom, collections

I am learning about DOM collections.  The textbook I'm using had the following Javascript code for iterating through the elements of the links collection:

```
var linksList = document.links;
for (var i = 0; i < linksList.length; ++i)
{
    ...
    [code to print links to HTML paragraph]
    ...
}
```

Just for fun I changed the loop to a `for ... in` style loop:

`for (var i in linksList)`

and afterwards noticed that my script was now generating 3 more links than before, and each of them was "undefined."

1) What are these undefined links, and why are they accounted for in a `for ... in` loop, but not the loop governed by `document.links.length`? (obviously `length` is 3 shorter than "true" length which includes the 3 mystery links)

2) How do I view collection using developer tools?  If I could do this, perhaps I could answer the previous question myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `document.links` returns an array-like object, that while providing `length` property and supporting indexing, has other properties, that show up in `for in` loop.